React, Flask, Nginx: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing
I have a React frontend served by Nginx, requesting a Flask API that is served by Gunicorn combined with Nginx (acting as a reverse proxy). Both frontend and backend run on the same machine, on ports 3000 and 8000 respectively. That means that the frontend requests the backend on 127.0.0.1:8000.
While testing in my local dev environment, all works as expected. On the other hand, the app deployed on a VPS doesn't: requesting http://public-ip-address:3000/ will return:
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource
at http://127.0.0.1:8000/. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
Status code: 200.

I am aware of the Same Origin Policy which requires to manage CORS. I do this in the Flask API as follows:
CORS(
    app,
    resources={
        r"/*": {
            "origins": [
                "http://localhost:3000",
                "http://127.0.0.1:3000",
                "http://public-ip-address:3000"
            ]}},
    supports_credentials=True
)

So my guess would be that I messed up the reverse proxy block file configuration:
server {
    listen 8000;
    server_name _;

    # Custom headers for reverse proxy
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    location / {
        include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/path/to/unix/socket/file.sock;

        # CORS headers for allowing cross-origin requests
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
    }
}


for context and clarity, let me provide the frontend block file as well:
server {
    listen 3000;
    server_name _;
    root /path/to/react/app/build;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

EDIT: it seems to me that this behavior is a quirk of Flask_cors and Nginx which are not among the topics of the suggested answer, therefore this is not a duplicate question.

Web origins do not contain a trailing slash. Try with "origins": ["http://localhost:3000", "http://127.0.0.1:3000", "http://public-ip-address:3000"] instead.

Does this answer your question? Access from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked even though I've allowed https://example.com/

I'm afraid it doesn't @jub0bs. Dropping the trailing slash didn't help

There may be multiple reasons for failure. Leaving the trailing slash definitely is one.
